# Prove universal morphism is unique up to unique isomorphism.

Tags: category-theory, universal-property

I'm following along Wikipedia page(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_property) on universal property, and this seems it should be trivial, but I couldn't finish the proof.

The definition I am working with: [image]

The problem
[image]

So I want to prove that if $(A, u)$ and $(A', u')$ are universal morphism from $X$ to $F$, then there exists unique isomorphism $k: A \rightarrow A'$ such that $u' = F(k) \circ u$.

My attempt:

For any $B \in C$ and $f: X \rightarrow F(B)$, there exists unique $h: A \rightarrow B$ such that $f = h \circ u$.

Letting $B = A'$ and $f = u'$, we see that there exists unique $k: A \rightarrow A'$ such that $Fk \circ u = u'$.

This shows existence and uniqueness. We only need that $k$ is isomorphism, but this is the part I cannot prove.

Similarly, there exists unique $k': A' \rightarrow A$ such that $Fk' \circ u' = u$.

Plugging into each equation, we get

$$Fk \circ Fk' \circ u' = F(k \circ k') \circ u' = u'$$

$$Fk' \circ Fk \circ u = F(k' \circ k) \circ u = u$$

but this of course doesn't imply $F(k \circ k') = id$, so it seems useless.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've derived the equation $F(k'\circ k)\circ u=u$. So $k'\circ k\colon A\to A$, but since $(A,u)$ is a universal morphism, by definition there is a unique morphism $h\colon A\to A$ such that $F(h)\circ u=u$. (This is the condition you get when you apply the universal property to the universal morphism itself.) But $h=1_A$ also works, so by uniqueness, $k'\circ k=1_A$.

Reversing the roles, as you've already done, shows $k\circ k'=1_{A'}$, so $k$ and $k'$ are isomorphisms.

Comment: Thank you very much!